# find out all available gtk icon sizes

Tags: icons, xfce, gtk

With [gtk_icon_size_register ()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/gtk2-Themeable-Stock-Images.html#gtk-icon-size-register) an app can register a new icon size, but how can I find out on the console, which icon sizes exist?

I hope to be able to adjust icon-sizes of apps (in xfce4) that don't respond to

```
xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Gtk/IconSizes -s "gtk-large-toolbar=32,32:gtk-small-toolbar=24,24:gtk-menu=32,32:gtk-dialog=88,88:gtk-button=32,32:gtk-dnd=32,32"
```

like for example the menues and icons in sublime are still really tiny on my hdpi screen

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what each theme provides.

1. Check which of them you are using.
2. Then look for its index file in `/usr/share/icons`

Example: `/usr/share/icons/elementary-xfce/index.theme`

```
[Icon Theme]
Name=elementary Xfce
Comment=Smooth modern theme for Xfce
Inherits=adwaita,gnome,hicolor

Example=directory-x-normal

#Directory list
Directories=actions/16,actions/22,actions/24,actions/32,actions/48,actions/64,actions/96,actions/128,actions/symbolic,animations/16,anim
ations/22,animations/24,animations/32,animations/48,animations/64,animations/128,apps/16,apps/22,apps/24,apps/32,apps/48,apps/64,apps/96
,apps/128,apps/symbolic,categories/16,categories/24,categories/32,categories/48,categories/64,categories/96,categories/128,categories/sy
mbolic,places/16,places/22,places/24,places/32,places/48,places/64,places/96,places/128,places/symbolic,mimes/16,mimes/24,mimes/32,mimes
/48,mimes/64,mimes/96,mimes/128,mimes/symbolic,devices/16,devices/22,devices/24,devices/32,devices/48,devices/64,devices/96,devices/128,
devices/symbolic,emblems/10,emblems/16,emblems/22,emblems/24,emblems/32,emblems/48,emblems/64,emblems/128,emblems/symbolic,emotes/16,sta
tus/16,status/22,status/24,status/32,status/48,status/64,status/128,status/symbolic,notifications/16,notifications/22,notifications/24,n
otifications/32,notifications/48,panel/16,panel/22,panel/24,panel/48,stock/16,stock/22,stock/24,stock/32,stock/48,tools/22,

[actions/16]
Size=16
Context=Actions
Type=Fixed

[actions/22]
Size=22
Context=Actions
Type=Fixed

[actions/24]
Size=24
Context=Actions
Type=Fixed

[actions/32]
Size=32
Context=Actions
Type=Fixed

[actions/48]
Size=48
Context=Actions
Type=Scalable

[actions/64]
Size=64
Context=Actions
Type=Scalable

[actions/96]
Size=96
Context=Actions
Type=Scalable

[actions/128]
Size=128
Context=Actions
Type=Scalable

[actions/symbolic]
Size=16
Context=Actions
MinSize=8
MaxSize=512
Type=Scalable

...
```

Keep in mind, that it `Inherits=adwaita,gnome,hicolor`, so parent themes may have additional sizes. Non-standard sizes could be covered by `Type=Scalable` icons.